# casting error using recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, common-table-expression

I am trying to generate a list of numbers from -1 to 1 in .1 increments. The following is code is giving me an error:

```
WITH NumTab AS(
    SELECT -1.0 AS Num 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT Num + .1
    FROM NumTab 
    WHERE Num <= 1.0
)
SELECT * FROM NumTab
```

> Types don't match between the anchor
>   and the recursive part in column "Num"
>   of recursive query "NumTab".

I have tried casting all the numbers to `decimal(2,1)` with no change in results. There must be something obvious I am missing...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cast both parts equally

```
WITH NumTab AS(
    SELECT cast(-1.0 as decimal(20,10)) AS Num 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT cast(Num + .1 as decimal(20,10))
    FROM NumTab 
    WHERE Num <= 1.0
)
SELECT * FROM NumTab
```

Decimal(2,1) should work, but cast the full column, not the Num part only for the part after UNION

If you inspect the output after these statements:

```
SELECT -1.0 AS Num into dummytable
select Num + .1 as num2 into dummytable2 from dummytable
exec sp_columns dummytable
exec sp_columns dummytable2
```

Ouptut:

```
TABLE_NAME   COLUMN_NAME  TYPE_NAME  PRECISION  LENGTH  SCALE
dummytable   Num          numeric    2          4       1    
dummytable2  num2         numeric    3          5       1
```

The literal -1.0 is implicitly cast to decimal(2,1).  However, when you add another literal of .1 (which is implicitly decimal(1,1)), it has the potential to tip the decimal(2,1) data to a decimal(3,1), e.g. if `9.9 + 0.9 = 10.8`, which is a decimal(3,1).  So the types differ between the anchor and recursive portions.

Comment: Can you say why the cast is necessary at all?

Comment: Just a minor correction, the where clause should be `WHERE Num < 1.0`